# Output from BAT to FORM

Tags: output

I am trying to make a Minecraft Server Creator and in the form i want the server BATCH file to output to the form?

Any ideas.

Im using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate if thats any help?

Comment: You have to be more specific. I'm just assuming that you want to create an application with form, which calls some batch file, and you want the output of that batch be available somewhere in the application? What have you tried already?

Comment: Basically, A minecraft server runs in a BATCH file, I want that batch file output to go into a TextBox on the form, For a Example. http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-tools/1263406-program-tt-server-creator-an-easy-way-to-create-a

Comment: That was made in Visual Studio but the only thing is, Its not Open Source so i cant see how he/she made it.